# dictionary from JSON to CSV

Tags: python, json, csv, dictionary

I have a JSON file containing a dictionary with many key-value pairs. I want to write it to a single CSV. One way to do this is simply to iterate through each key:

```
csvwriter.writerow([f["dict"]["key1"], f["dict"]["key2"],
                    f["dict"]["key3"], ... ])
```

This would be very tedious.

Another possibility is simply to use

```
csvwriter.writerow([f["dict"].values()])
```

but it writes everything into one column of the CSV file, which is not helpful.

Is there a way I can write each value into one column of the CSV file?

Comment: Does the order of keys in the JSON file need to preserved? If not, what determines the order they are to appear in the columns of the CSV file?

Comment: no. seems to be random.

Comment: Hmm, seems like having/allowing the data appear in random columns of the CSV would make it difficult to process afterwards.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your comment. Yes it needs to be preserved

Comment: In that case you can control the order in the answer you've accepted by listing them in the desired order in the `fieldnames` list. However that will have to be manually created (and possibly maintained) and it may not match the order they appear in the JSON file itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use a [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter)

The example in the official documentation is pretty straight-forward:

```
import csv

with open('names.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Baked', 'last_name': 'Beans'})
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Lovely', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Wonderful', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
```

Note that you *must* provide `fieldnames` to the constructor.  If you're certain that all your dict have the same keys and don't care about the order of the output, you can just use `list(first_dict)` to get the column names, otherwise, you'll want to come up with a way to specify them more explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) is good for this kind of thing.

I would read the JSON file into a pandas dataframe ([link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html)). Then write it as a CSV ([link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)).

```
import pandas as pd

#read in the json
df = pd.read_json("json_path_here")

# write the csv
df.to_csv("csv_path_here")
```

Answer (score 1):

Equivalent to your code:

```
csvwriter.writerow(f["dict"].values())
```

**Note:** For this, your dictionary should be of `collections.OrderedDict` because Python's default dictionaries are not ordered. Hence, you'll end up with different order in each row.

**Alternatively**, better way to achieve this is using [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) (for which you don't need ordered dict):

```
csvwriter.writerow(f["dict"])
```

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7 and when I enter the asterisk, it says "SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax". Is there anything I need to do?

Comment: Can you share with me the value of: `f`. Just do `print f` and share it with me

Comment: {"stats": { "item1": 3153, "totalPlayerScore": 0, ... }}

Comment: I think a possible reason may be I'm using csv.writer and not csv.dictwriter. Let me try dictwriter

Comment: Use dictwriter and use: csvwriter.writerow(f["dict"]). Does that work? (Note: it is without `*`)

Comment: Yes it works. thanks for your help. It happens that my problem is substantially more complicated than this, so I'll post another question which contains the more complicated version of my problem.

Comment: Does it worked with `**f["dict"]` or `f["dict"]`? Actually I am on my mobile right now and just provided you the expected solution. It will be great if you may tell me what was the issue. I will get to know something new :)

Comment: The actual issue is described in my latest post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086440/multiple-dictionaries-to-csv-in-python

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to use `csv.DictWriter`. The following, which works in both Python 2 and 3, shows how to create a CSV file that will automatically have the key/value pairs in the same order as they appear in the JSON file (instead of requiring a manually defined `fieldnames` list):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import csv
import json
from io import StringIO

# in-memory JSON file for testing
json_file = StringIO(u'{"dict": {"First": "value1", "Second": "value2",'
                                '"Third": "value3", "Fourth": "value4"}}')

# read file and preserve order by using OrderedDict
json_obj = json.load(json_file, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)

with open('pairs.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(json_obj["dict"].keys())  # header row
    writer.writerow(json_obj["dict"].values())
```

Contents of **`pairs.csv`** file written:

```
First,Second,Third,Fourth
value1,value2,value3,value4
```